# HTTP Status 501 - SpringBoot, SpringSecurity, Tomcat, login

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-security, spring-boot

I am relatively new to the world of java. I am building a web application where I use Spring. So here's the case:

We have deployed the web app to our development server , and have it out in the open. This is how our network administrator explained it (don't really understand it but might be important for you):

55.555.55.5 is a NAT port to 77.77.77.77  ; 77.77.77.77 is an apache proxy server that makes a connection to 99.9.99.999.
We tell this server - 55.555.55.5 on http port to connect to 99.9.99.999 on port 8080 and give the client a connection on port 80 of 55.555.55.5; At the moment it is 1:1 connection...

And here is the problem:

On http://localhost:8080/myapp/ and on http://99.9.99.999:8080/myapp/ (our development server) everything works fine.

But on http://55.555.55.5:8080/myapp/ which is visible to the clients if I load the login page and right away login its ok, but if I wait like a couple of minutes on the page I get this:

> HTTP Status 501 - Method email=something%40gmail.com&password=somethingGET is not implemented by this servlet for this URI
>
> type Status report
>
> description The server does not support the functionality needed to fulfill this request
>
> Apache Tomcat/8.0.32

This is really strange and I don't know why it's happening?

Comment: did you compare the libraries in the tomcat installations on your servers?

Comment: Just made some tests and if I try to log in up until the 20th second after going to the login page it works fine, but if I try to log in on the 21st second  or later it fails. ps I will compare the libraries JimHawkins. 10x for the suggestion.